# Three.js Event Listener in scene renderer

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, kinect

This will be a "strange" question, because my code works. I just want to check if it can be tweaked because I dont have programming experience.
I wrote a script that gets a stream of kinect joints and plots them on a three js scene on an coordinates system with a webgl renderer.
At first I create a set of spheres, based on Stemkoski's examples and then add the event listener for the json skeleton that arrives in the update function, so I can update the spheres coordinates and have it moving. 
The only problem that this creates is that now I cannot rotate the coordinates system with my mouse (while I could when I was testing it with static spheres or with pulsing spheres, as in Stemkoski's example). 
So the first question is how can I correct this problem.
The second, more complex question is this : Is this a correct practice? I may not be a developer but I have learned that when my gut says this is awkward or bad practice, it probably is.. Any help and suggestions, appreciated.
Oh, and I have implemented this for only one skeleton in the scene. I will try to make it for more skeletons but I ll wait for your input here in case this all could be simpler and better written.
Here's the relevant code, the initialization of the sphere/joints and the update function:

```
WholeSkeleton = new THREE.Object3D();

particleAttributes = { startSize: [], startPosition: [] };


var totalParticles = 20; //=num.skeleton.joints //add later variable number
var radiusRange = 50;
for (var i = 0; i < totalParticles; i++) { // INITIALIZE THE SKELETON JOINTS POSITION 

    var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 'rgb(255,0,0)' });
    var jointSphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
   //initialize positions
    jointSphere.position.set(0, 0, 0);


    WholeSkeleton.add(jointSphere);
    // add variable qualities to arrays, if they need to be accessed later
    particleAttributes.startPosition.push(jointSphere.position.clone());

}

scene.add(WholeSkeleton);
}

function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
render();
update();
}

function update() {


document.addEventListener("skeletonEvent", function (e) {

    jsonObject = e.detail.SkeletonSourceData;

   // for (var i = 0; i < jsonObject.Skeletons.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < jsonObject.Skeletons[0].Joints.length; j++) { //only for skeleton 0.

            var incoming=jsonObject.Skeletons[0].Joints[j];
            var joint = WholeSkeleton.children[j];


            joint.position.x = (particleAttributes.startPosition[j].x + incoming.Position.X)*30;
            joint.position.y = (particleAttributes.startPosition[j].y + incoming.Position.Y)*30;
            joint.position.z = (particleAttributes.startPosition[j].z + incoming.Position.Z)*10;

        }
  //  }

});

}
```

--

Comment: I'm quite certain you don't want to re-add the same event listener on each invocation of `update`... Just add the event listener once during your setup.

Comment: @jcaron Hmm I think I understand what you re saying. So, I could put the listener in the init function, get the jsonObject from there and then just leave the for loop as is in the updater? That could work?

Comment: Not sure why you would need anything (related to this) in the `update` function, **unless** what you are getting is a speed, not a position (but that does not seem to be the case) or you need to "smooth" the movement from the previous position to the new one. Not knowing in which conditions/at what rate you receive the events, it's difficult to guess.

Comment: @jcaron you are right, I'm getting a position. I get a constant stream of skeleton data from kinect. These are json objects, and I am constantly reading the joint coordinates at whatever frequency I get them(I guess a minimum of 24fps). So I wanted to add them on a 3D scene and watch the skeleton move. Anyway, I ll try to implement it with the listener outside of the update and see what happens